# Calling a submit() within an inline frame returns an object error on Windows 7 only. XP and Vista fine. IE8

Tags: javascript, windows, internet-explorer-8, submit

We have an application that we use an inline frame to submit data to a Notes server.  A document.forms[0].submit(0) call is done in the frame, however, on Windows 7 IE8 machines, it results an object error.  Our XP and Vista machines with IE8 work fine.  Does Windows 7 work differently than XP and Vista even though they are all IE8?

Comment: Form is in parent frame and the target of the form is the iFrame ?

Comment: We are trying to submit the form in the Iframe by a call done from a "document.forms[0].submit(0)" within that iframe